# How to make collisions affect rotation only on X and Z axes in lib Bullet?

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

Having a terrain and some mesh objects placed as STATIC I throw capsule like objects onto my world (for example agents my engine wants to navigate).

I need tham to bahaive as normal collidable objects yet I need tham not to rotate on one axis at all (for me it is `Y`) so agents always are in a "standing" vertical position like so:

[image]

thay will be able jump and move... So I wonder how to make collisions affect rotation only on X and Z axes in Bullet?

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods to do this, but I think the best for this case is to apply setAngularFactor() to the agent rigid body with the vector (0, 1, 0)